# undo scale data pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import MinMaxScaler
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

df = spark.createDataFrame([
   (0, Vectors.dense([5.0, 0.1, -1.0]),),
   (1, Vectors.dense([2.0, 2.1, 1.0]),),
   (2, Vectors.dense([3.0, 10.1, 7.0]),)
], ["id", "features"])

scaler = MinMaxScaler(inputCol="features", outputCol="scaledFeatures")
scaler_model = scaler.fit(df)
scaled_data = scalerModel.transform(df)
```

`scaled_data` is the transformed data.

How I can do a inverse scale to analyse results after fitting a machine learning model ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there no "inverse\_transform" method for a scaler like MinMaxScaler in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092114/is-there-no-inverse-transform-method-for-a-scaler-like-minmaxscaler-in-spark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MinMaxScaler` adds scaled features as a new `scaledFeatures` column, so your actual data isn't lost.

You can use the `features` column to analyse your `scaledFeatures` output column before using it into a machine learning model.