# Is there any inverse transform in PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

In python sklearn preprocessing, there exist inverse_transform()
so I can easily inverse my data
like below

```
scaler.inverse_transform(table)
```

I'm using
from pyspark.ml.feature import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler
Is there any inverse transform in pyspark??
or should I make my own function to inverse data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there no "inverse\_transform" method for a scaler like MinMaxScaler in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092114/is-there-no-inverse-transform-method-for-a-scaler-like-minmaxscaler-in-spark)